# OpenWRT - Missing dependencies for package

Tags: openwrt, makefile

I'm trying to compile this [package](https://github.com/adde88/hostapd-mana-openwrt) using the OpenWRT/LEDE SDK, however when I try to compile it I get this error:

```
Package hostapd-mana is missing dependencies for the following libraries:
libc.so.0
libcrypt.so.0
libgmp.so.10
libm.so.0
libncurses.so.5
libpanel.so.5
libpcap.so.1.3
libstdc++.so.6
```

How do I fix this?

Makefile:
   [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Hdwk9R71)

Comment: You need to include the complere Makefile directly in the question. Pastebin links are worthless in a history perspective.